# Python - Kmeans - Add the centroids as a new column

Tags: python, k-means, centroid

Assume I have the following dataframe. How can I create a new column "new_col" containing the centroids? I can only create the column with the labs, not with the centroids.

Here is my code.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

numbers = pd.DataFrame(list(range(1,1000)), columns = ['num'])

kmean_model = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
kmean_model.fit(numbers[['num']])

kmean_model.cluster_centers_
array([[699. ],
       [297. ],
       [497.5],
       [899.5],
       [ 99. ]])

numbers['new_col'] = kmean_model.predict(numbers[['num']])
```

Comment: The dataframe you made (numbers) has 1000 records, but the number of centroids are just 5. So it is not recommend to append the centroid to your dataframe. Do you want to know just centroid values?

Comment: I want to assign the dataframe values to the nearest centroids. Likewise in this case is an example, I have a real problem in which I have >100k records and I have to assign them to centroids, but the problem is the same as in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple. Just use `.labels_` as follows.

```
numbers['new_col'] = kmean_model.labels_
```

Edit. Sorry my mistake.

Make dictionary whose key is label and value is centers, and replace the new_col using the dictionary. See the following.

```
label_center_dict = {k:v for k, v in zip(kmean_model.labels_, kmean_model.cluster_centers_)}
numbers['new_col'] = kmean_model.labels_
numbers['new_col'].replace(label_center_dict, inplace = True)
```

Comment: I just need cluster_centers_, not labels values

Comment: Excellent answer, that is what I was looking for :D

Comment: how can I put how far a row is from the cluster center? I want to put this in a different column